# Error: 413 “Request Entity Too Large” Html + MVC WCF service

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, wcf

Basically, I created one page into HTML then i want to send two files XML & SVG. Both files are converted to text and then send to the WCF service in the MVC project. but it gives "Error: 413 “Request Entity Too Large”. I tried a small file & its works. but more than 200kb is not working well.
i tried to convert stream, but I had no luck. so I decided to convert it into string & pass it.

My HTML Page -

[image]

My WCF code -

[image]

also, i checked online solution for that but its already done.

[image]

ERROR -

[image]

If anyone knows, how to convert string to Stream in javascript, then tell me. I am able to accept stream value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution after spending 1-2 days. look into this url

https://cmatskas.com/upload-files-in-asp-net-mvc-with-javascript-and-c/

Comment: You should provide a summary of information from this URL source in case the URL becomes unavailable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Maximum limit for receiving files in WCF like this:

```
        WebServiceHost webServiceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(UploadService), uri);
        WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        webServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IUploadService), binding, "WebServiceHost");
        webServiceHost.Open();
```

And you can try setting the upload size limit in HTML web.config.